# Plot real and imaginary part of function

Tags: plotting, complex

I have the following function:

```
f3 = (99. (2154.43 - 100. lh^2.))/lh^1. - (0.0609773 ((2154.43 - 100.lh^2.)/lh^1.)^7.30317)/(-4.64159 - lh)^6.30317
```

If I plot it, in that specific interval, I get:

```
Plot[{f3}, {lh, 4.45, 4.85}]
```

[image]

If instead I plot both the real and the imaginary part I get:

```
Plot[{Re[f3], Im[f3]}, {lh, 4.45, 4.85}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
```

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5hkm.png]

**I don't understand why when I plot *only* the real part, the function is not shown for values smaller than 4.64**. Indeed, the imaginary part is not zero for values greater than 4.64 either, as is shown in the following graph:

```
Plot[{Im[f3]}, {lh, 4.78, 4.8}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[{f3}, {lh, 4.45, 4.85}]` only plots if the argument `f3` is real! Only for`x>4.64` the imaginary part of f3 vanishs!

Comment: Does this mean that there is a threshold regarding the imaginary part of a complex number, below which M. treats it as a Real number?

Comment: No I don't think so. Plot only tries to find the region where f3 is real. That's why for example `Plot[Exp[I x],{x,0,2 Pi}]` gives no output!

Comment: This is what I thought. However, in the last graph in the question, I show that the imaginary part for values greater than `4.64`, although very small, it is different from zero. Hence, `f3` is not real; nevertheless, in the first graph, the function it's plotted for those values.

Comment: With your last plot you only show, that the imaginary part is of order `10-13` and that's the precision used in the numerical evaluation.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My point is that the imaginary part is different from zero for values both smaller and greater than `4.64`. However, the real function is not shown for values smaller than `4.64` but it is shown for values greater than `4.64`.

Comment: Plot is a numerical(!)  function. Values smaller `10^-13`(depending on the WorkingPrecision) are assumed to be zero!

Comment: Ah, I see thanks! If you copy and paste this answer in the answer place I will accept it :)

Comment: You are encountering precision issues that result from doing calculations using machine precision. To get precise calculations you need to track and control precision by using exact or [`arbitrary-precision numbers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html). To avoid conflicts with subsequent specification of desired working precision, start by expressing `f3` with exact numbers by using [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html).